# Gstreamer ffdec_h264 missing

Tags: camera, streaming, gstreamer, pipeline

I am running this script to view cameras on network:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=1234 ! "application/x-rtp, payload=127" ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

I am getting this error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ffdec_h264"
```

I am getting error with `ffdec_h264`. I have all the packages from g-streamer but I don't know which one I am missing.
when I run `gst-inspect | grep 264`
I get this output:

```
    h264parse:  legacyh264parse: H264Parse
x264:  x264enc: x264enc
videoparsersbad:  h264parse: H.264 parser
typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264
rtp:  rtph264pay: RTP H264 payloader
rtp:  rtph264depay: RTP H264 depayloader
```

Which shows I don't have this `ffdec_h264`
which package I am missing?

Comment: Could you give us a little detail about your system and GStreamer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might depend on your OS/distribution and GStreamer version.

Over here (Debian jessie, GStreamer 0.10.36) `gst-inspect ffdec_h264` gives the following output:

```
Factory Details:
  Long name:    FFmpeg H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 decoder
  Class:        Codec/Decoder/Video
  Description:  FFmpeg h264 decoder
  Author(s):    Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>, Ronald Bultje <rbultje@ronald.bitfreak.net>, Edwar$
  Rank:         primary (256)

Plugin Details:
  Name:                 ffmpeg
  Description:          All FFmpeg codecs and formats (system install)
  Filename:             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so
  Version:              0.10.13
  License:              GPL
  Source module:        gst-ffmpeg
  Binary package:       FFmpeg
  Origin URL:           http://ffmpeg.org/
```

So on my system, `ffdec_h264` is in the `gst-ffmpeg` module (which was installed using `apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to enter this command and have an idea what h264 decoder you have with gstreamer, in other words what Gstreamer is calling it.

> gst-inspect | grep "h264"